# How do I access a UDF DLL in Firebird Embedded?

Tags: firebird

I tried building a UDF for Firebird.  I was able to compile the DLL and register the UDF with the database, but I can't actually run it.  Every time, I get an error:

```
invalid request BLR at offset 63.
function [FUNCTION_NAME] is not defined.
module name or entrypoint could not be found.
```

I've tried dropping the UDF DLL in the same folder as the application, and in the same folder as the database, but either way it never seems to load it.

When I tried Googling for help, all the results I got back seemed to either deal with making it work on an FB server by putting it in the UDF folder for your server (which doesn't apply as I'm using FB Embedded) or with fixing permissions issues on a FB sever by editing the conf file (which doesn't apply as I'm using FB Embedded).

So, how do I determine/configure the correct place to put the UDF DLL **if I'm using FB Embedded?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think that by default Firebird expects the UDF DLLs to be in the subdirectory (relative to the fbembed.dll file) named `udf`.
You can configure the UDF paths via `firebird.conf` file, using `UdfAccess` parameter. The conf file which comes with installation has a explanation how to use the parameter. Also the `README_embedded.txt` file contains good explanation how the embedded server files should be placed.